# Convert tibble/dataframe to JS array in R

Tags: javascript, r, json, jsonlite

Say you have the following data:

```r
library(tibble)

offset <- tribble(
  ~index, ~month,
  0, "Jul",
  1, "Aug",
  2, "Sep",
  3, "Oct"
)
```

How would one go about converting `offset` into the following JavaScript friendly array?

```
'offset': {
  0: 'Jul',
  1: 'Aug',
  2: 'Sep',
  3: 'Oct',
}
```

I've tried using `library(jsonlite)` via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251148/11167644) but it doesn't provided the desired outcome:

```r
library(jsonlite)

toJSON(offset)
#> [{"index":0,"month":"Jul"},{"index":1,"month":"Aug"},{"index":2,"month":"Sep"},{"index":3,"month":"Oct"}]

toJSON(offset, dataframe = "rows")
#> [{"index":0,"month":"Jul"},{"index":1,"month":"Aug"},{"index":2,"month":"Sep"},{"index":3,"month":"Oct"}]

toJSON(offset, dataframe = "columns")
#> {"index":[0,1,2,3],"month":["Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct"]}

toJSON(offset, dataframe = "values")
#> [[0,"Jul"],[1,"Aug"],[2,"Sep"],[3,"Oct"]]
```

My experience with JavaScript is laughably limited so any help would be much appreciated!

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this near enough:

```
month <- offset$month
names(month) <- offset$index
cat(rjson::toJSON(list(offset = month)))

{"offset":{"0":"Jul","1":"Aug","2":"Sep","3":"Oct"}}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!